# How to count up numbers in a label in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl

I have a program containing a button and a label, I want the label to count up numbers so fast from 0 to 100000 for example.

I tried `System.Diagnostics stopwatch` but it's not as I want it.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sw: TStopwatch;
begin
  sw := TStopwatch.StartNew;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  sw: TStopwatch;
begin
  sw.Start;
  label1.Caption := IntToStr(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TStopWatch` (which you are not using correctly, BTW) is not the kind of counter you are looking for.  You need a simple `Integer` variable instead, eg:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Counter: Integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Counter := 0;
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Counter);
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Inc(Counter);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(Counter);
  if Counter = 100000 then Timer1.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: amazing, MANY THANKS BUDDY